# How to set the previous clicked answer on going next question in angular 11

Tags: arrays, ngfor, angular11

[image]
Hello..  I m building a quiz app in angular 11, my issue is that when i click on one answer of question and going to next question previous clicked answer removed automatically how can fixed the answer on click it shouldn't remove when i go to next question.answer is appreciable thanks

```
    **HTML**
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h3> {{questionList[currentQuestion]?.questionText}}</h3>
                </div
            </div>
            <div >
              <ol *ngFor="let option of questionList[currentQuestion]?.options; let i=index">
                    <li  (click)=disble(questionList[currentQuestion].options,option,i)>
                       <label><input type="radio" name="options" value={{option}}> {{option}}</label><hr>

                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button [disabled]="currentQuestion===0"(click)="previousQuestion()">/i>Previous</button>
            <button [disabled]="currentQuestion===(questionList.length-1)><(click)="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
          </div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


 @Component({
  selector: 'app-questions',
  templateUrl: './questions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questions.component.css']
})



   constructor(private router:Router) { }
    public questionList:any=[];
    public currentQuestion:number=0;

   ngOnInit(): void {}

//suffle function for suffle the index of an array
   shuffle(array:any){
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
     return array;
  }

 getAllQuestions(){
   this.qzservice.getQuestion().subscribe(res=>{
     console.log('get all questions',res.questions)
     this.questionList=res.questions;
    var suffleArray= this.shuffle(this.questionList);
      console.log('shuffled array',suffleArray);
   })
 }
 nextQuestion(){
  this.currentQuestion++;
   }

 previousQuestion(){
  this.currentQuestion--;
 }

disble(data:any,opton:any,ind:any){
 var gvnAnswer =opton;
    var corrAnswer=this.questionList[this.currentQuestion].answer
if(gvnAnswer==corrAnswer){
     console.log('right answer')
   else{
     console.log('Incorrect answer')
}

}
```

**quiz-service.service.ts**

```
 questionUrl= '/assets/questions'
getQuestion(){
    return this.http.get<any>("assets/questions.json")
  }
```

**questions.json**

```
{
    "questions":[
            {
                "questionText":"The Kanjli Wetland in India is located in the state of -",
                "options":[
                    " Punjab",
                    "Rajasthan",
                    "Tamil Nadu",
                    "Gujarat"
                    ],
                "answer":" Punjab"
            },
        {
            "questionText":"Llanos grasslands are found in -",
            "options":[
                " Argentina",
                "Venezuela",
                "Paraguay",
                "Brazil"
                ],
             "answer":"Venezuela"
        },
        {
            "questionText":"Who was the last ruler of Shunga dynasty?",
            "options":[
                " Pulinda",
                "Andhrak",
                "Devbhuti",
                "Vasumitra"
                 ],
             "answer":"Devbhuti"
        },
        {

            "questionText":"In which session did the Indian National Congress adopt the resolution for Puma Swaraj?",
            "options":[
                " Calcutta",
                "Lahore",
                "Madras",
                "Lucknow"
             ],
             "answer":"Lahore"
          },
        {
            "questionText":"Sputnik vaccine of Corona is developed by which of the following countries?",
            "options":[
                " India",
                "China",
                "Canada",
                "Russia"
                ],
            "answer":"Russia"    
        }        
    ]       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the given answer in some `array` or `object`. so that when you revisited your question you will be able to pull the given answer for the question.

```js
     const answers = new Map<any, any>();

   disble(data:any,opton:any,ind:any){
     var gvnAnswer =opton;
     var corrAnswer=this.questionList[this.currentQuestion].answer
     this.answers.set(this.currentQuestion, gvnAnswer);
     if(gvnAnswer==corrAnswer){
       console.log('right answer')
     else{
       console.log('Incorrect answer')
     }
  }
 
  isChecked(option) {
    return this.answers.get(this.currentQuestion) === option;
  }
   <label>
     <input
                type="radio"
                name="fav_language"
                value="{{ option }}"
                [checked]="isChecked(option, i)"
              />{{ option }}</label
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i m beginner so const answers = new Map<any, any>();  new for me kindly elaborate it

Comment: more details on Map you see this  link https://www.javatpoint.com/typescript-map

Comment: Or you use Record as well https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

Comment: i used Map  but it didn't work in my case because didn't get index value outside disble function  and i m trying to store select answer data in other array. can you help more on it.

Comment: you can create a running example on stackblitz. I will fix help you.

Comment: Here is my stackblitz code link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvckkr?file=src/app/app.component.html   kindly check and and fix it thanks

Comment: fixed your code and updated answer

Comment: I had implemented as above code but it didn't work as thought ,kindly see the stackblitz code but vaibhav sir it is very nice approach but bad luck for me

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-73bmdn

Comment: thank you very much sir now it is working ,i searched on google but i didn't found correct solution ,i m beginner and it will help me to learn more.